# How to get a tasks sub tasks when they are not assigned to user and project

Tags: asana

The Asana API is quite limiting in its ability of fetching tasks. This is especially true when fetching tasks that are not assigned to a user and a project as the endpoint to fetch tasks requires either an assignee or a project.

When adding sub tasks to a task in Asana, they are by default not assigned to a user nor to a project. In Asana they show nicely in the right pane, however via the API there is no way to get them. Or do I miss here anything?

Sorry, found it!

GET /tasks/task-id/subtasks

However, I would still be interested in an answer related to tasks without assigned user and project in general.

Answer (score 0):

Our current thinking is that the best way to do this is to expose the Search feature via the API, which would allow you to find people, projects, and tasks using the same sort of predicates currently exposed in the project. There's no timeline on this yet, but we'd love to hear if it sounds like that would solve your use-case!

Comment: Most important would be to query all tasks in a workspace in one request. Would reduce the number of required requests dramatically. A timestamp as request parameter would allow to request just changed tasks since a certain point in time, which would keep the number of response objects low as well. Further, the response should include all tasks, even when they have no assignee and no projects. Filter options would be of course welcome.